# Need regex to match first occurence of a character in a string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, neo4j-apoc

I have a sql query as string and I need a regex to match first question mark (?) in the string

```
select * from something where a = ? and b=? and c=?
```

The regex should match only the first occurrence of question mark. I will be using this regex in Neo4j-apoc library ([apoc.text.replace function](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index30.html)). Unlike Perl/Java etc. this library does not provide any flag or api to get first match. So I have to completely rely on regex to match only the first character.

I have tried some of the below regex but no luck

These Regexes matches nothing

```
(?<=^[^?]{0,1000})[?]
```

These Regexes matches all non-existence characters and all question marks

```
[?]?
([?])?
([\?])?
([\?])??
([?])*?
```

These Regexes matches all question marks

```
([?])+?
[?]+?
```

Can someone help me write this Regex?

Comment: Are there always 3 question marks? If not, would a regex that captures the first `?` as group 1 work?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://regex101.com/r/PBkfbp/3)

Comment: @Bohemian, the above query is just a sample, there can none or n number of question marks. I need to match only the first one. I cannot use group in neo4j-apoc library. I need a regex that uniquely matches only first ?.

Answer (score 1):

Well I came up with a *strange* solution, but maybe you take this:
    `(?<!\?)\?{1}(?!.*?\?)|(?<=\?)\?{1}(?!.*?\?)`
will match only the **last** `?`.
So, although you aren't able to directly find out the first, you may *reverse* you string and then find the last.
I used [Regex101](http://regex101.com) to test it.

**[UPDATE]:**
it finds the **last** occurrence of `?` before a `\n`.

Comment: Looks helpful, I will try it and see if I can use this. Thanks

Comment: @Fayaz you're welcome.  And thanks for the question, it was very interesting to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `([^?]+)(\?)(.+)`

and you can get first question mark with `$2`

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/PBkfbp/5)

Comment: This regex matches entire string along with first question mark. When I use this in neo4j-apoc (apoc.text.replace function), it will replace entire string. I need to match only the first question mark and not other part of string.

Answer (score 0):

If your regex engine supports [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<`, to select only the first question mark you could use:

[`(?<=where a = )\?`](https://regex101.com/r/36ks0L/1/) or without the where [`(?<=a = )\?`](https://regex101.com/r/36ks0L/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use *lookbehind* with a quantifier like `(?<=^[^?]{0,1000})`.

In such a case (at least in *regex101.com*) you get an error message:
`{0,1000} A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width`.

To match the **first** `?` you can use `^[^?]*(\?)`, meaning:

- `^` - Start of the string.
- `[^?]*` - A (posiibly empty) sequence of chars other than `?`.
- `(\?)` - The char you want to capture.

The first `?` will be the content of the first capturing group.

### Edit

Another solution, possible if you use *PCRE* version of regex:

```
^[^?]*\K\?
```

meaning:

- `^[^?]*` - Match "intitial" sequence of chars other than `?`.
- `\K` - "Forget" what you have matched so far and start matching from here.
- `\?` - Match `?`.

This way your **whole match** is the first `?`, without any capturing groups.